# -webkit-background gradients on th/td elements causes navbar collapse to slow down massively

Tags: html, css, css-tables, linear-gradients

I've been attempting to add a linear gradient to text in my tables and up until now, it was successful. Everything looked amazing until I tried accessing the navbar on my android device. On my two pages that contain tables, the navbar lagged when collapsing and it felt horrible.

After researching the issue online, I realised it was an issue relating to the excessive use of `webkit` on my th/td elements. I completely removed the entirety of the independent background relating to the th/td elements and the issue had gone. I understand the logic behind it slowing down, but how can I remedy the situation?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf6hqj0g/)

One Table:

```css
table:not(#tableTeam1, #tableTeam2) tr:nth-of-type(1) td {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  background: white;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

table:not(#tableTeam1, #tableTeam2) tr:nth-of-type(1) th {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  background: white;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

td,
th:not(.teamsleft) {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, #ffffff, #656161);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
      <div class="scrolling outer">
        <div class="inner">
          <table class="table table-hover table-dark table-condensed">

            <tr>
              <th scope="col" class="firsth" id="topleft">Name</th>
              <td scope="col">Positioning</td>
              <td scope="col">Handling</td>
              <td scope="col">Reflexes</td>
              <td scope="col" id="topright">Average</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>

              <th>Jimbo</th>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3.0</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>

              <th>Michael</th>
              <td>2.5</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>2.83</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>

              <th class="bottomleft">Dwigth</th>
              <td>2.5</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>2.83</td>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a second table that is roughly four times the size as this.

Is there a more efficient way of applying gradients to table elements? Or should I just consider removing them completely?

Answer (score 0):

**You no longer need prefixes for different browsers . You can refer community questions about it.**

Else extent I see your fiddle you have applied same `gradient` . So you can overcome your problem by using this code

```
*{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right,#ffffff, #656161);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

And apply any change in gradient respectively to `elements` if there .

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the navbar still lags on dropdown.

Comment: Forget to mention brother **You no longer need prefixes for different browsers**

Comment: You can reffer to questions on Stack overflow about it

Comment: What do you mean? I don't need to reference -webkit, just background on its own?

Comment: Yes  prefix are removed from latest versions of browser

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that

Comment: See if this will solve your problem and try for different browsers as caution .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236415/discussion-between-daad-and-datamsc).